# VS Code dev container: Failed to download VS Code Server

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I update VS Code, my dev container breaks with `Failed to download VS Code Server`:

```
[16413 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a
[16413 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /home/<my_username>/.vscode-server/bin/d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a_1602875933619
[16432 ms] 
[16432 ms] 
[16470 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[16686 ms] Failed to download VS Code Server (https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a/server-linux-x64/stable): HTTP 403 - Forbidden
```

I'm pretty sure this is because it's not using the proxy.

My devcontainer.json refers to an image, not a dockerfile, and HTTPS_ and HTTP_PROXY are baked in. Also the lowercase vars of the same name.

I have `http.proxy` and `https.proxy` configured in `devcontainer.json`.

I have the proxy set in the daemon config and my docker config in my profile. Other web traffic uses the proxy.

I've tried invoking code with `--proxy-server`.

I've tried setting `/etc/wgetrc`. No dice to any of these.

This started hapening around 1.47 or so.

Once up, this container has no issues using the proxy. My workaround is to get the commit ID from the failure in the log or by running `code -v` locally, then attach a shell to the running dev container and run this stanza:

```
commit=d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a   # <= replace this

cd ~/.vscode-server/bin
mkdir ${commit}
curl https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit}/server-linux-x64/stable -L --output ${commit}.gz
tar --no-same-owner -xz --strip-components 1 -C ./${commit} -f ./${commit}.gz
```

To say that my team and I are tired of this would be an understatement. What's the real fix?

Comment: Hi. I just started to use docker and I use it with WSL.
I'm facing the same problem and I would like to know if you found any fix.
Also you said "My devcontainer.json refers to an image, not a dockerfile", can you tell me how you do that ?

Comment: Sadly, I'm still doing this process, although I've scripted it

Comment: To use an image: build image outside VSCode, however you normally do that; in devcontainer.json, use the field `"image": "your_image_name"` (instead of dockerfile or dockercompose)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is fixed in 1.55.0.

w00t w00t!